# MongoDB sort by multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am making with posts that can be voted on.  Each vote contributes to a post's score.  Each post has an id and a score.  I am trying to query to MongoDB to find hot posts.  I want to do this by sorting by when the post was posted, taking the 100 most recent, and then sort these 100 by score.  Post is a mongoose Schema with _id and score in it.  I have tried:

```
Post.find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(100).sort({score: -1}).exec(function(err, posts) {
    if(err){
        res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

However, this causes an error.  How can I fix it or achieve my desired sorting in a different way?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`aggregate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) to perform multiple sorting stages:

```js
Post.aggregate([
    {$sort: {_id: -1}},
    {$limit: 100},
    {$sort: {score: -1}}
], function(err, posts) { ...});
```